# express.json() is an unknown property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Typescript doesn't recognize the `express.json()` function although many tutorials state this code should compile as it is.
Is there something I have done wrong?

Example tutorial where this is stated to be working: https://auth0.com/blog/node-js-and-typescript-tutorial-build-a-crud-api/#test-the-express-api-endpoints
Moreover I know this works in normal Node.js but have never tried it in Typescript.

```
const version = require('../package.json').version;
import express from 'express';
    
console.log("Application is running on version " + version);

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(7777);
```

Compiler output:

```
app.ts:10:17 - error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Express'.

10 app.use(express.json());
                   ~~~~
Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `tsc --outDir dist && node dist/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-15T14_34_22_294Z-debug.log
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                                   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
    // "declaration": true,                         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                             /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                  /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an 'override' modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your tsconfig.json setup? try `import * as express from 'express'`

Comment: @MarkoCen 
When I use your import the following is shown for the .json() call:
```Property 'json' does not exist on type '{ default: Express; application: Application; request: Request; response: Response; Route: typeof Route; Router: (options?: RouterOptions | undefined) => Router; static: (root: string, options?: ServeStaticOptions | undefined) => (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse, next: (err?: any) => any) => void; }```

I also updated the question and added the tsconfig.json.

Comment: woww yea changing from `import express from 'express ` to `import * as express from 'express` did it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of your devDependencies.

It should look something like that.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be identified in the package.json file.
Somehow the version of the @types/express package was defined with the version "github:types/express" which seems not to be the most current.

The fix was to update the package.json file from

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc --outDir dist && node dist/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "github:types/express",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

to (only the version of "@types/express" has been changed)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc --outDir dist && node dist/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changing from `import express from 'express'`  to `import * as express from 'express'` did it for me